# How to turn an array into the keys of a Hash and another array into the values of the same hash?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have 2 arrays:

```ruby
array1 = ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
array2 = ["o", "l", "l", "e", "H"]
```

I want the array1 elements to become the keys in a new Hash, and the array2 elements to become the corresponding values in the same Hash. Can someone please suggest how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Note that there are two `"l"`s in the "key" array, while Hashes can't have duplicate keys.  Any solution will have either `"l" => "e"` or `"l" => "l"`, but not both.  Something to be aware of if you're going to have duplicates in the array that becomes the keys.

Comment: Thanks, I am very new to programming and I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 4):

```
array1 = ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
array2 = ["o", "l", "l", "e", "H"]
p Hash[array1.zip(array2)]
# >> {"H"=>"o", "e"=>"l", "l"=>"e", "o"=>"H"}
```

Comment: here is another one- `array1 = ["H", "e", "k", "l", "o"]
array2 = ["o", "l", "l", "e", "H"]
p Hash[array1.zip(array2)]
# >> {"H"=>"o", "e"=>"l", "k"=>"l", "l"=>"e", "o"=>"H"}`

Comment: @kitch6041 What @@darshan mentioned is valid, if you have duplicate keys, then you need to think of about the data-structure how would you represent it. If not then,if you want can go with my solution too while there are several right answers. Which one suits your need accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two `"l"`s in the "key" array, while Hashes can't have duplicate keys.  Any solution will have either `"l" => "e"` or `"l" => "l"`, but not both.  If that's okay, then @RubyLovely's solution is great.  If you want to preserve a mapping for each pair, an Array of Hashes might be appropriate:

```
array1 = ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
array2 = ["o", "l", "l", "e", "H"]
array1.zip(array2).map{|pair| Hash[*pair]}
# => [{"H"=>"o"}, {"e"=>"l"}, {"l"=>"l"}, {"l"=>"e"}, {"o"=>"H"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @RubyLovely is how I would do it but for the sake of variety here is another solution:

```ruby
array1.each_with_index.reduce({}) do |memo,(x,i)|
  memo[x] = array2[i]; memo
end
# => {"H"=>"o", "e"=>"l", "l"=>"e", "o"=>"H"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing it this way, you would not need to create an intermediate array, and hence would be more effective than doing so.

```
h = {}
array1.zip(array2){|k, v| h[k] = v}
h # => {"H"=>"o", "e"=>"l", "l"=>"e", "o"=>"H"}
```